# Is Separation of Variables possible here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked to solve the differential equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^{2}.$$
The issue I'm finding is that each attempt to isolate $y$ adds a $dx$ next to it. For example, if I multiply both sides by $dx$, I get
$$dy = dx-y^{2}dx,$$
and subtracting $y^{2}dx$ yields $$y^{2}dx-dy=dx.$$
This is technically a step closer to complete separation of variables (all $y$ variables are on the same side), but the $dx$ next to $y^{2}$ problematizes things. To illustrate this, dividing $dx$ yields 
$$y^{2}-\frac{dy}{dx}=1,$$
essentially right where I started. Is there a rule regarding Separation of Variables I'm missing, or is the technique not viable for this Differential Equation?

Comment: How is the last the same as the first? Is there anything wrong with your signs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^{2}\implies\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=dx\implies \arctan y=x+c$$

Comment: welp i guess im an idiot

Comment: @BrianLee Do not discourage for this kind of mistake, you will see it better the next time! Bye